# How software development goes on between these different phases (Dev, Test, Stage and Prod)

Tags: testing, lifecycle

Please can you explain how the software development goes on between these different phases step by step

(development, Unit testing, integration testing, qualification testing, acceptance testing, staging environment and production)

And please before down vote my question, Kindly advice as I am bit confused over here.

Comment: This is a process question, where SO is primarily a software development site. You might have more luck on a SE site like Product Management (http://pm.stackexchange.com/). It's also very broad, which is why people are voting to close. You may want to try asking a more narrow question that can be answered objectively.

Comment: @neontapir at least they can advice as you did and indicate where should i post my question before down vote it. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain how we handle that.

**dev:** Here is the newest version from the code repo and developers do the tests here. Connected to dev backend systems (SAP, Jira, MSSQL,...)

**test:** Place where our business tests our applications, also connected to test environments. Here we have automatic tests running during night (selenium, integration tests)

**stage:** is a copy (same version) from prod system but connected to test systems. Here you can reproduce issues from prod but don't mess prod data.

**prod**: not much to say here. here are our customers...

unit testing is only on local host or maybe during check-in to repo, depending on the rules you have.

I hope this helps you